# Sort a list of dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I have a huge list of data frames that I want to sort by name

**Example**:

```py
Data_frames_list = [sensor 1 (South), sensor 6 (North), sensor 3 (South), sensor 1 (North), ...]
```

I would like to sort it by the sensor number (those are data frames names containing tons of rows).

**Final result example**:

```py
Data_frames_list = [sensor 1 (South), sensor 1 (North), sensor 2 (South), sensor 2 (North), sensor 3 (South), ...]
```

Does anybody have an idea how I could proceed?

Comment: Use ordered dictionaries, then sort by keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to get the variable name before sorting. You can get the variable name by creating a function like:

```
def namestr(obj, namespace, prefix='sensor'):
    for name in namespace:
        if namespace[name] is obj and name.startswith(prefix):
            return name
```

then you can use this method to sort the list like:

```
Data_frames_list.sort(key=lambda df: namestr(df, globals()))
```

in `namestr()` function, `prefix` argument is used because there could be issues in sorting if there's another variable pointing to dataframe as `globals()` will return dictionary of all current global symbol table

NOTE: The code will sort based on the variable name which is a string, so `sensor 11` will come before `sensor 2`.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated ! :)